# How to identify latent variables in single-cell RNA-Seq data

Tags: scrnaseq, clustering, pca, gene-ontology, noise

I have a single-cell RNASeq sample, in which I'd like to identify latent variables (e.g. response to stress) that I think might be affecting the clustering.

The approach I was planning to use is to reduce the dimensionality of the dataset using one algorithm among:

- PCA
- ICA
- NMF

Then identify the most important biological processes for every component (e.g. in each Principal Component), and then finally regress out the processes that might not be relevant to the analysis or that might affect the downstream clustering.

I have a few questions:

- Are there issues in this approach?
- Is there a collection of gene sets (similar to MSigDB) that can be used to identify noise latent variables?
- Which algorithm (PCA, ICA, NMF, or others) is more suited to this kind of analysis?

Comment: ..... PCA + tSNE

Comment: @Michael why tSNE? How do you use tSNE in such case?

Comment: Its brilliant.... :-)

Comment: The larger question is how do you know you are regressing out the right stuff?

Comment: And if the so called latent variable is taking up so much of your variance... how can you be sure of the response of your interest

Comment: @StupidWolf it's a good point, however, I don't want to regress out the full Principal Component. I want to analyze which biological processes are driving the clustering and run the same analysis twice (non-regressed, and regressing only the biological processes of interest, e.g. cell cycle). My interest is more methodological (PCA, ICA and NMF work in slightly different ways, for example).

Comment: Cool.. hmm very interesting actually. I try and find the suitable scRNAseq to give it a shot. Just to clarify, yes if it is cell cycle etc we can identity it, what if it's something more ambiguous? And about regressing it out, for finding clusters etc it's not a problem. If we need to do actual inference, I would include these as covariates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to identify latent variables, PCA is probably not going to work. NMF might be worth trying. You might want to check out a method called consensus NMF (cNMF) (https://elifesciences.org/articles/43803) published in eLife. The author described some latent variables corresponds to cell types, while others corresponds to cell-cycle or metabolic states of cells.

Comment: Thanks! I will read it now!